# Performance of duplicate computations

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I wonder if it's worth  to make computation one time and store the result or it's faster to do twice the computation?

For example in this case:

```
float n1 = a - b;
float n2 = a + b;
float result = n1 * n2 / (n1 * n2);
```

Is it better to do:

```
float result = (a - b) * (a + b) / ((a - b) * (a + b));
```

?
I know that normally we store the result but I wonder if it's not faster to do the addition instead of calling the memory to store/retrieve the value.

Comment: The ultimate answer is - it depends. Measure, always measure.

Comment: It is not a performance issue, it is a code-readability issue. What makes the code easier to read? Whether an additional float or two is declared is negligible.

Comment: For trivial expressions, like you show, the compiler will likely optimize it to the same thing.

Comment: To make the answer more complicated, but the question less important, many compilers perform *common subexpression elimination* on source codes.  The general rule, when working with a good optimising compiler, is that the programmer should leave such operations to the compiler, which will do it better.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination

Comment: @Fureeish Or just see [what the compiler does](https://godbolt.org/z/uSF328)

Comment: All forms of the calculation In this case either gives the value `1.0f` (if `abs(a) != abs(b)`) or undefined behaviour otherwise.   Doing any steps of the calculation *at all* is therefore quite questionable, let alone a question of whether to do it once or multiple times.    A simple `float result = 1.0f` will do.

Comment: related: [Will the compiler optimize repeated math computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949388/995714), [Does gcc optimize c++ code algebraically and if so to what extent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34879992/995714), [Do C++ compilers optimize repeated function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42126460/995714)

Answer (score 6):

It really depends: For trivial examples like yours, it does not matter. The compiler will generate the same code, since it finds the common sub-expressions and eliminates the duplicated calculations.

For more complicated examples, for example involving function calls, you are better off to use the first variant, to "store" intermediate results. Do not worry about using simple variables for intermediate storage. These are usually all kept in CPU registers, and the compiler is quite good in keeping values in registers.

The danger is that with more complex calculations the compiler may fail to do the common sub-expression elimination. This is for example the case when your code contains function calls which act like a compiler boundary.

Another topic is that with floating point, even simple operations like addition are not associative, i.e. (a+b)+c is different from a+(b+c), due to artifacts in the lowest bits. This often also prevents common subexpression elimination, since the compiler is not allowed to change the semantics of your code.

Comment: Great point in distinguishing the floating point arithmetic from other ones in terms of what the compiler may optimise.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the expression into smaller expressions and giving them sensible names gives You several benefits:

- It decreases [cognitive load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_load).
- The longer expression could be now easier to understand and verified correct.
- The line of code could be shorter which makes it easier to read and adhere to coding standards.

In C++ a temporary variable could also be marked `const`, then this also allows the compiler to better optimize the expressions.

But optimizations should be measured before they are discussed and used as arguments. **Fast** usually comes from the choice of data structures and used algorithms.

In general code should be written to be understood and be correct, and only then should it be optimized.

---

```
const float difference = a - b;
const float sum        = a + b;

const float result     = difference * sum / (difference * sum);
```

Comment: Yes on the style reasons, but `const` is irrelevant for optimization, as long you compile with optimization enabled.  The compiler will analyze the lifetime of the value of a variable, and see that if `sum` isn't used after computing `result`, it doesn't need to keep the value anywhere except a register.  If you do disable optimization, of course everything is terrible ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394))

Comment: @PeterCordes Of course! *if* the used compiler has life time analysis. Whereas `const` makes it quite explicit what can be done with the variable. (Of course, *if* the used compiler knows what to do with it)

Comment: All mainstream C compilers do such optimizations, usually as part of transforming through an [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) internal representation (e.g. GCC's GIMPLE, or LLVM-IR, or whatever MSVC or ICC use).  I can't recall a case where adding `const` to a local variable has ever improved optimization, although I've mostly looked at output of good compilers (gcc and clang).  (Globals are a different matter, of course).  Still, this is very basic stuff that I'd expect any ahead-of-time optimizing compiler to do.